# Xamarin.Forms FFImageLoading CachedImage не сразу отображает изображение из файла

Tags: xamarin

Xamarin.Forms FFImageLoading CachedImage не сразу отображает изображение из файла.

Файл находится в папке Resources/drawable как андроид ресурс

```
<ff:CachedImage Source="logo2.jpg"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HeightRequest="104"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                LoadingDelay="0"
                FadeAnimationEnabled="False"
                Grid.Row="0" />
```

Обычное изображение отображается сразу

```
<Image Source="logo2.png"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       HeightRequest="104"
       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       Grid.Row="0" />
```

Подключение в android проекте

```
FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true);
```

Так же ведет себя и с svg.

Comment: Пробывали заранее в память закешировать? Команда: ImageService.Instance.Load[file].Preload();

Comment: Да, это решает проблему, но костыльно. Приходится все изображения заранее кэшировать в вьюмодели, нельзя это в xaml прописать?

Comment: Это советует и сам разработчик. Была аналогичная проблема на гитхаб https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/796 или использовать LoadingPlaceholder

Comment: LoadingPlaceholder не помогает, придется делать так, все равно альтернативы этой библиотеки нет(

Answer (score 0):

В релизной версии данная проблема не особо заметна, в целом можно сказать, что ее и нет на небольших изображениях, но если на странице много svg изображений (использовал для иконок кнопок) или большие (типа фотографий) лучше все-таки кэшировать заранее.